# Can $e^x$ be expressed as a linear combination of $(1 + \frac x n)^n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, conditional-convergence

Can $e^x$ be expressed as a linear combination of $(1 + \frac x n)^n$? In other words, does there exist an infinite sequence $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb N_0}$ such that $$e^x = a_0 + \sum_{1 \leq k < \infty} a_k \left(1 + \frac x k\right)^k$$
for all $x \in \mathbb R$? Call the series on the right $s(x)$.

I can answer the question in the negative when the series is absolutely convergent. In the conditionally convergent case, I'm not so sure. My thoughts were to use the fact that:

$$e^{x - \frac{x^2}{2k}} \leq (1+ \frac x k)^k \leq e^{x}$$

and use the lower bound when $a_k$ is negative, and the upper bound when $a_k$ is positive. This gets stuck because it's not always the case that if some $b_k$ is a decaying sequence then $\sum_{k} \frac{b_k}{k}$ is convergent.

The strengthened inequality $$e^{x - \frac{x^2}{2k}} \leq (1+ \frac x k)^k \leq e^{x - \frac{x^2}{2k} + \frac{x^3}{3k^2}}$$ looks like it might make more progress...

---

[EDIT 2019/08/14 14:00 GMT]

**This is the solution in the absolutely convergent case, given by lemmas 1 and 2**:

> **Definition**: Let $s(x) = a_0 + \sum_{1 \leq k < \infty} a_k \left(1 + \frac x k\right)^k$.

Lemmas and proofs follow:

> **Lemma 1**: If $s(x)$ converges absolutely for *some* $x\geq 0$, then $s(x)$ converges absolutely for *all* $x \geq 0$.

#### Proof

Pick an $x_0 \geq 0$ for which $s(x_0)$ converges absolutely.

By the condition stated in the lemma, the series $\sum_{1 \leq k < \infty} |a_k| \left|1 + \frac {x_0} k\right|^k$ must converge. We also observe that $|a_k| \leq |a_k| \left|1 + \frac {x_0} k\right|^k$ is true for all $k$. So by the Direct Comparison Test, the series $\sum_{0 \leq k < \infty} |a_k|$ must also converge. In other words, $s(0)$ is absolutely convergent.

Consider now any $x \geq 0$. The series $\sum_{0 \leq k < \infty} |a_k| e^{x}$ converges because it is equal to $e^{x} \sum_{0 \leq k < \infty} |a_k|$, which we proved to be convergent in the previous paragraph. We observe that $|a_k| \left|1 + \frac {x} k\right|^k \leq |a_k| e^{x}$ is true for all $k$. So by the Direct Comparison Test, the series $|a_0| + \sum_{1 \leq k < \infty} |a_k| \left|1 + \frac {x} k\right|^k$ must also converge. So by the definition of absolute convergence, we have that $a_0 + \sum_{1 \leq k < \infty} a_k \left(1 + \frac x k\right)^k=s(x)$ converges absolutely, where $x \geq 0$ was arbitrary.

$\blacksquare$

> **Lemma 2**: If $s(x)$ converges absolutely when $x \geq 0$, then for large enough $x$ we have that $e^x > s(x)$.

#### Proof

Let $z_n(x) = |a_0| + \sum_{1 \leq k < n} |a_k| \left(1 + \frac x k\right)^k$.

Pick some $\epsilon < \frac 1 2$.

Observe that there must be a large enough $n$ such that $z_\infty(0) - z_n(0) \leq \epsilon$.

Using the triangle inequality, we have that:
$$\begin{aligned}
|s(x)| &\leq z_\infty(x)\\
&\leq z_n(x) + (z_\infty(x) - z_n(x))\\
\end{aligned}$$

Since $z_n(x)$ is a polynomial, there is a large enough $X$ such that all $x \geq X$ it's true $z_n(x) < \epsilon \cdot e^x$. So we have that
$$\begin{aligned}
|s(x)| &<\epsilon\cdot e^x + (z_\infty(x) - z_n(x))\\
&\leq \epsilon\cdot e^x + (z_\infty(0) - z_n(0)) e^x\\
&\leq \epsilon\cdot e^x + \epsilon\cdot e^x\\
& = 2\epsilon \cdot e^x\\
&< e^x.
\end{aligned}$$
The claim above that $z_\infty(x) - z_n(x) \leq (z_\infty(0) - z_n(0)) e^x$ follows from 
$$\begin{aligned}
&|a_k| \left(1 + \frac x k\right)^k \leq |a_k| e^x\\
\implies &\sum_{k \geq {n+1}}\left(1 + \frac x k\right)^k \leq \sum_{k \geq {n+1}}|a_k| e^x\\
\implies & z_\infty(x) - z_n(x) \leq (z_\infty(0) - z_n(0)) e^x
\end{aligned}$$

We are done.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: One approach: Weierstrass M-test can be used to establish uniform convergence of the series (and of those of the derivatives) on some interval with $x=0$ as its upper bound thus one should be able to term-by-term differentiate the series and evaluate at $x=0$. Doing this $n$ times you should get something like $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k = 1$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k/k^n = 1$ for $n=2,3,4,\ldots$ which allows you to deduce the $a_k$'s and get a contradiction.

Comment: @Winther Your approach only works for the absolutely convergent case (which I had already solved, but you've provided another way of doing). It leaves the conditionally convergent case.

Comment: Yes I implicitly assumed the coefficients had to be positive. Another possible way to look at it is to use that $(1+x/k)^k$ is basically $e^x$ for large $k$. Thus around $x=0$ we have $e^x = \sum_{k=0}^N a_k (1+x/k)^k + e^x \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty a_k + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is some tiny correction (which likely also has tiny derivatives). Solving for $e^x$ and analyze the resulting series might be easier (if you can control $\epsilon$ well enough). Don't know how easy it is to make this precise though.

Comment: Not all coefficients are positive.  In order to get the $x^2$ term, we need some coefficients negative.  (In order to get the $x$ term, we need $a_0 = 0$.)

Comment: Is there any question left about my answer ? ---  Maybe you are looking for another type of explanation but then please add that to your question.

Comment: @user90369 I don't think your answer is complete. The one below yours may be.

Comment: @user90369 Specifically, it's not clear why the coefficients in the power-series representation of $a^x$ need to change continuously with $a$. Your answer is taking the limit of the coefficients as $a \to e$.

Comment: It's interesting though that you provide a series representation of $a^x$ for $a < e$. And how the coefficients approach $0$ as $a$ approaches $e$.

Comment: I'm reading your explanation more carefully

Comment: For my reasoning, remember that for any value $δ>0$ your series exists for $(e−δ)^x$ . 
So if there exists your series for $e^x$, a transition with $δ→0+$ would be possible in any small steps. 
Consider $|e^x−(e−δ)^x|<ϵ$ with $ϵ>0$.

Comment: About Lemma 2: What can you say about the case $0<x<X$ ? There is no argument, that $|s(x)|<e^x$ here too. This means: It's still possible, that a series of your type exists for $e^x$ , if  $0<x<X$ .

Comment: @user90369 Using the Weierstrass M-test, it can be shown that the series converges uniformly under the above conditions. By Morera's theorem, it must converge to an analytic function. By uniqueness of analytic functions, $e^x \neq s(x)$ even when $0 < x < X$ except at finitely many points

Comment: What I meant is: Your considerations in Lemma 2 are good and correct, but uncomplete. With other words: "We are done." is much too early. Your whole argumenation there depends on large enough  
n
 and large enough  
x
 . If people read carefully what you have written, they have an uncomplete answer because of case $x<X$. Would be nice, if you add what is needed for a complete argumentation, if you want to communicate this to other interested people. And please: Morera's theorem refers to the complex number range which makes it necessary to transfer your calculations on $x\in\mathbb{C}$ .

Comment: You said: "Specifically, it's not clear why the coefficients in the power-series representation of $a^x$ need to change continuously with $a$. Your answer is taking the limit of the coefficients as $a→e$." --- Of course, if we assume that the series is valid for $e^x$ . But we see that the series is divergent for $a=e$, therefore we get a contradiction and $e^x$ is not possible. The base is that $a^x$ has this series representation for all (!) values $1/e < a < e$ . And it's not only $e^x$, it's for all $a^x$ with $a\geq e$ for which the series doesn't exist, ...

Comment: ... although the series is convergent for $\delta < 0$ in my answer. This has to do with the branches of $x^{1/x}$, that's another topic.

Comment: @user90369 I'm still not convinced that your answer is complete. The argument should have the structure of "Assume $e^x$ can be expressed as $a_0 + \sum_{1 \leq k < \infty} a_k \left(1 + \frac x k\right)^k$. Then something follows. Then something else follows. Contradiction." I don't see that. Also, if $e^x > s(x)$ is true for large enough $x$, then it shows that $x\mapsto e^x$ is a different function from $x\mapsto s(x)$. You seem to want something stronger than that, but that's not what I asked

Comment: @user90369 OK why do you assume that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty |a_k-(\frac{k\frac{\ln a}{a})^k}{k!})|(1+\frac{x}{k})^k \to 0$? This is why your answer is incomplete whether you accept it or not

Comment: Yes, correct, my explanation is not correct. Forget the inequation, it's senseless here. What I used was the equation $e^x−a^x =... \to 0$ . And  I wanted to use the linear independency of the terms $(a^k − \frac{(k\frac{\ln a}{a})^k}{k!})(1+\frac{x}{k})^k$ here, which becomes difficult to proof. I have been persuaded by you to think in this direction, as you always go out from unknown $a_k$. --- But: In my answer I have used $a_k(z):=\frac{(zk/e)^k}{k!}$ with $a_k(z)\to a_k$ if $z\to 1$ . Means: I have already given a specific route to a_k. So: Are the $a_k$ unique for $e^x$ (as I think) ?

Answer (score 2):

Let $R_n(z)=\sum_{1 \leq k \le n} a_k \left(1 + \frac z k\right)^k$. Assuming the hypothesis we will show:

1: $R_n(z) \to e^z-a_0$ uniformly in the disc $|z| \le \frac{1}{2}$

2: $\sum_{1}^{\infty}{\frac{a_k}{k^q}}=0, q \ge 1$ arbitrary integer

3: $a_k=0, k \ge 1$

We use that if $|z| \le \frac{1}{2}, k \ge 1$, $|(1+\frac{z}{k})^k-(1+\frac{z}{k+1})^{k+1}| \le B|\frac{1}{k^2}|, B>0$ constant, which follows from $k\log(1+\frac{z}{k})=z-\frac{z^2}{2k}+O(\frac{z^3}{k^2}), |z| \le \frac{1}{2}, k \ge 1$, so $(1+\frac{z}{k})^k=e^{z-\frac{z^2}{2k}+O(\frac{z^3}{k^2})}$ and then subtracting the relations for $k, k+1$ since the $O$ terms are at most $\frac{1}{8k^2}$ in absolute value and $|\frac{z^2}{2k}-\frac{z^2}{2k+2}| \le \frac{1}{8k^2}, |z| \le \frac{1}{2}$

We also note that $|(1+\frac{z}{k})^k| \le (1+\frac{|z|}{k})^k \le e^{|z|} \le e^{\frac{1}{2}} <e$ since the binomial coefficients are positive and the triangle inequality works

For simplicity let $b_k(z)=(1+ \frac z k)^k$, so if $|z| \le \frac{1}{2}$

$|b_k(z)-b_{k+1}(z)| \le B|\frac{1}{k^2}|$

$|b_k(z)| \le e$

Then since $\Sigma{a_k} \to 1$ by hypothesis for $x=0$, it folows that $|\sum_{N}^{M}a_k| \le A$ for all $N \le M$ and some constant $A>0$, while $|\sum_{N}^{M}a_k| \to 0, N,M \to \infty$ so if we pick arbitrary $\epsilon >0, |\sum_{N}^{M}a_k| \le \epsilon, M>N >N(\epsilon)$ and then we sum by parts:

$|R_M(z)-R_N(z)|=|\sum_{N+1}^{M}a_kb_k(z)|=|(A_{N+1}(b_{N+1}-b_{N+2})(z))+(A_{N+2}(b_{N+2}-b_{N+3})(z))+....(A_{M-1}(b_{M-1}-b_{M})(z))+(A_{M}(b_{M}(z))|$,

where $A_p=\sum_{N+1}^{p}a_k, p \ge N+1$

So $|R_M(z)-R_N(z)| \le A\sum_{N+1}^{M-1}{B|\frac{1}{k^2}}|+e|A_M| \le AB\frac{1}{N}+e\epsilon, M>N > N(\epsilon)$ which shows that $R_N(z)$ is uniformly Cauchy in $|z| \le \frac{1}{2}$. But this means $R_n(z)$ converges uniformly to an analytic function $f(z)$ on the disc of radius $r=\frac{1}{2}$ and since we know by hypothesis that $f(x)=e^x-a_0$ on the $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ segment it follows by the identity principle that $f(z)=e^z-a_0$ and this is 1 above

Now, we can differentiate term by term and get $R_n(z)' \to e^z$ uniformly on the  disc of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ and then plugging $z=0$ we get $\sum_{k \ge 1}a_k=1$ hence $a_0=0$, hence $R_n(z) \to e^z$ uniformly on the above disc.

Subtracting we get $\sum_{k = 1}^n\frac{a_kz}{k}(1+\frac{z}{k})^{k-1} \to 0$ uniformly which clearly implies $\sum_{k = 1}^n\frac{a_k}{k}(1+\frac{z}{k})^{k-1} \to 0$, hence $\sum_{k \ge 1}\frac{a_k}{k}=0$

($zf_n(z) \to 0$ uniformly on the disc of radius $r$, means that for any $\epsilon >0$ there is $N(\epsilon), |zf_n(z)| \le \epsilon, |z| \le r, n \ge N(\epsilon)$

Schwarz lemma implies $|zf_n(z)| \le \frac{|z|}{r}\epsilon, |z| \le r, n \ge N(\epsilon)$ or $|f_n(z)| \le \frac{1}{r}\epsilon, |z| \le r, n \ge N(\epsilon)$)

But now (with all convergences below being uniform) we can integrate on the straight line from $0$ to $z$, $\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{a_k}{k}(1+\frac{w}{k})^{k-1} \to 0$ and get $\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{a_k}{k}(1+\frac{z}{k})^{k} \to 0$.

Subtracting gives $\sum_{k = 1}^n\frac{a_kz}{k^2}(1+\frac{z}{k})^{k-1} \to 0$, hence $\sum_{k = 1}^n\frac{a_k}{k^2}(1+\frac{z}{k})^{k-1} \to 0$, hence $\sum_{k \ge 1}\frac{a_k}{k^2}=0$. A clear induction (integrate, subtract, divide the $z$) gives 2 above

3 is a trivial consequence of 2 since wlog we can assume $\sum|a_k| < \infty$ in 2 by going to $b_k=\frac{a_k}{k^2}$ which is absolutely convergent since $a_k$ is bounded and which clearly satisfies 2; then if $p \ge 1$ is the first index for which $a_p \ne 0, |a_p|=a>0$ and with $A=\max|a_k| \ge a>0$ we easily find a large $q$ s.t. $A\frac{p^q}{(p+m)^q} \le .0001\frac{a}{(p+m)^2}, m>1$ as $(1+\frac{m}{p})^{q-2} \ge (1+\frac{1}{p})^{q-2} \to \infty$ with $q$ for fixed $p$, leading to a term with absolute value $a$ plus sum that is at most $.0001a\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ in absolute value being zero and that is impossible.

So all $a_k$ must be zero if 2 is satisfied and we are finally done!

Comment: let $p \ge 1$ the first index $|a_p|=a>0$, $A = \sup|a_k| < \infty$.As $(1+\frac{1}{p+m})^q \ge (1+\frac{1}{p+1})^q \to \infty$ with $q$ for $m \ge 1$,there is $q$, $(1+\frac{1}{p+m})^{q-2}  \ge (1+\frac{1}{p+1})^{q-2} > 10^{100}Aa^{-1}p^2$, so when $\sum_{k \ge p}{\frac{a_k}{k^q}}=0$ is multiplied by $p^q$, the first term has absolute value $a$, while the rest are bounded by $Ap^2(10^{100}Aa^{-1}p^2)^{-1}\frac{1}{(m+p)^2}=10^{-100}a\frac{1}{(m+p)^2}$, so their sum is bounded by $10^{-100}a\sum_{k \ge 1}\frac{1}{k^2}$ - contradiction with all terms (first plus the rest) adding to zero

Comment: This is the same proof that Dirichlet series that are zero, have all coefficients zero, though here we just have that the associated Dirichlet series is zero only at all integers greater or equal to $1$, and since the coefficients are generally alternating (could be complex numbers too), we cannot conclude directly, but need to repeat the proof

Comment: More generally, the proof above shows that for any convergent series (conditionally enough, complex numbers ok), $\sum{a_k} \to a$, the series $\sum_{k \ge 1}{a_k(1 + \frac {z}{k})^k}$ is uniformly convergent near zero to an analytic function (most likely could make it entire but the estimates are trickier when $|z| >1$ so $|z|^2$ doesn't dominate $|z|^m, m \ge 2$ and then you can essentially try and identify coefficients if the result is known on the reals like here - many times it should work, here just the special nature of $e^z$ leads to a contradiction

Comment: The argument is above - if the first non-zero term is $|a_p|=a>0$, multiplying by $p^q$ gives $a_p+\sum_{m \ge 1}{a_{p+m}\frac{p^q}{(p+m)^q}}=0$ and then you just make $\frac{p^q}{(p+m)^q}$ very small times $\frac{1}{(m+p)^2}$, so the sum of all the other terms except $a_p$ are very, very small in terms of $a$ and that is the contradiction $0=a_p+$ very small; I put explicit numbers in the comment above but it is a standard argument

Comment: The problem was, that you were writing too complicate. The comment is much better then the text in your answer. What you mean is: $~\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=p}^\infty\frac{a_k}{k^q}=0~$ for all $~q\in\mathbb{N} ~~ \& ~~ |a_k|<\infty ~ \Rightarrow ~ a_p=-\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty\frac{a_{p+m}}{\left(1+\frac{m}{p}\right)^q} ~ \to ~ 0 ~$ for $~q\to\infty~$ .

Comment: Thanks for all of this. It's good stuff.

Comment: you are welcome!